# Hard binding in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me on how `hard binding` works in javascript?.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.a);
}
var obj = {
    a: 2
};
var bar = function() {
    foo.call(obj);
};
bar(); // 2
setTimeout(bar, 100); //
```

I am more interested in this function.

```
var bar = function() {
    foo.call(obj);
};
```

Why do we wrap `foo.call(obj)` inside another `function`?. We can use it directly right?.

```
setTimeout(foo.call(obj), 100); // still results in 2.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.call` (and `.apply`) methods simply let you *manually* set the value of `this` in the function being invoked.

So when you do `foo.call(obj)`, the value of `this` in `foo` will be `obj`.

As to the `setTimeout`, what you're doing is calling it immediately instead of waiting for 100ms. Change it to `10000`, and you'll see more clearly it doesn't wait.

So that's why the function is needed. You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`, and it will get invoked after the duration you provide.

---

There's also the `.bind()` method that creates a *new function* with its `this` value permanently bound to the first argument you provide. So that would actually be a hard binding example

```
setTimeout(foo.bind(obj), 100);
```

So in that example, a function is returned that will always have `obj` set as the this value. So now that `setTimeout` is being passed a function, it will be invoked after the given duration.

You can also bind arguments to the function. All arguments passed to `.bind()` after the first argument will be permanently bound to the returned function so that any arguments passed to that function will be placed after the bound ones.

Comment: The bind does the same as call/apply, but it returns a new function. This function can be used to pass in situation which accepts fn as params like seTimeout, callbacks etc right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need setTimeout to achieve hard binding.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}

var obj1 = {bar:10};
var obj2 = {bar:5};
var originalFoo = foo;
```

OriginalFoo now has the reference to foo

Now override foo function and use originalFoo.call to set the this context to always be that of obj1

```
foo = function() {
    originalFoo.call(obj1);
}

foo(); // returns 10
foo.call(obj2); //returns 10 even when obj2 passed as arg
```